# What does 'What I have come to know as' mean?

Tags: meaning

Here is a little excerpt:

> But after looking at the research, this is **what I've come to know as** a
> symptom for the deeper problem, which runs much more deeply, it's the
> root cause of this distraction.

Can I translate this into, I have learned that this is a symptom for the deeper problem.

When can I/should I use 'what I've come to know as...'?

Comment: The two don't mean exactly the same thing. Learning is not necessarily the same thing as coming to know something. (What is the source of the quotation?) Why do you need to paraphrase it?

Comment: I just wanted to get a better sense of what that means, and when to use it. No need to paraphrase. That excerpt is from someone's ted-talk.

Comment: Perhaps *… this is what I now understand to be a symptom of …*

Comment: The *deeper problem ... runs much more deeply* passes in speech, but that does not transcribe nicely. What does that middle phrase add?

Answer (score 1):

"(What) I've come to know" means knowledge that one has as a result of many experiences or facts. An alternative would be "what I've learned over time".